# How to know if Access Token expires in Google Api PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-api, access-token

How will I know if my access token has expired.

I'm using try and catch

```
try {
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?access_token='.$accesstoken);
print_r($result);
}
catch(Exception $e){
echo "Get new token";
}
```

but still it gets error from the file_get_contents then prints "Get new token"

If I want to use curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?access_token='.$accesstoken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

then what should I do to catch the error here?

```
//if error because access token is invalid,
  do here

// my fixed solution

 $response= json_decode($result);
 if($response->error){ // if result has errors
   echo "Get new token";
 }
```

Comment: What is your question? Do u want to know when to ask for new access token or how to ask for new access token?

Comment: @shadow Yes, I want to know if my access token has expired. I've edited my post with my solution. Please feel free to say any suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

probing this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}
```

will gives you:

```
{
  "audience":<your_client_id>,
  "user_id":<user_id_if_userinfo.profile_was_authorized>,
  "scope":"<authorized_scope_1> <authorized_scope_1>",
  "expires_in":<time_to_live>
}
```

or an error:

```
{"error":"invalid_token"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the exceptions. Check if the HTTP error code is 401(unauthorized). This means that your access token has expired and its the time u refresh your access token.

Comment: I highly doubt `file_get_contents()` throws an exception for *any* HTTP status code.

Comment: I've tried the try and catch that would catch the exceptions, but if I use the file_get_contents on the "try{ }" it does not go to the catch exceptions if unauthorized.

Comment: So I read about file_get_contents() and indeed it never throws HTTP errors. If you are not able to load data the value of result is FALSE. That means you should use some other function as Google API call can fail due to multiple reasons. Why don't you use Google API PHP client library here http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/