# Retrieve value from json_encode with callback function on PHP

Tags: php, callback, jsonp, json

How can I get my values from json_encode with a callback function

```
data({
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
});
```

I want to get the values of my response body so that I will know if there's an error using PHP.
I need to have a callback function to easily get my values via javascript.

Comment: What happens when you var_dump($response) ?

Comment: @AdamPointer I've edited my code above to show more details

Comment: `getThis({"data":"1234"});` is JavaScript, not JSON, so obviously `json_decode` won't work. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @netcoder Yeah, but I'm working on a server to client app. Calling the data on the server with a callback via Javascript. But the real problem is in here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953195/how-to-know-if-access-token-expires-in-google-api-php) that's why I want to manipulate this data to know if there's any response error.

Comment: As said in the other question's answer, the HTTP request response code will tell you if there's an error, not the response body. Just check the HTTP response code, no JSON parsing required.

Comment: @netcoder yes, your right but how can I do that? file_get_contents() can't throw any HTTP errors. That's my main problem there, but I wonder if curl can catch the response code to tell me if there's any error. I don't want to use any library for now.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan: Edit your question with the actual question and we'll help. This question is completely unrelated to what you've just asked.

Comment: @netcoder , there finished. Sorry about the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant var_dump($response) not var_dump($result) and I understand you properly, json_encode has converted your function to a string as you cannot convert a function to json and vice versa only arrays, objects and primitives such as strings.

This maybe a help... [PHP json_encode and javascript functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745248/php-json-encode-and-javascript-functions)

Comment: Thanks, but maybe Im gonna skip this. Nice reference for the future need :)